# How to select the root node using id, parent_id?

Tags: php, php-5.3

```
$users = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `users`)->rows();
$rootUser = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = 1")->row();
```

the output array is:

```
array(

 [0] => array(

  'id' => 1,
  'login' => 'test1',
  'parent_id' => 0

 ),
[1] => array(

  'id' => 2,
  'login' => 'test2',
  'parent_id' => 1

 ),
[2] => array(

  'id' => 3,
  'login' => 'test3',
  'parent_id' => 2

 )


)
```

How can I select all the nodes starting from the root node, using php, without mysql joins beacuse they have limit as far as I know only 61 joins is allowed,

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is root node?

Comment: it can by any node from the database that has an id, there are other nodes that can have parent_id, but I can't get all the nodes, because they are separated by levels, i mean the relation id and parent_id recursively, is there way the get them all using a php loop?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain your question little more?

Otherwise if you mean to select only root nodes, then you can use sql below:

```
  SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE parent_id=0
```